# Tic-Tac-Toe Java : Button Issues

Tags: java

I've created a little TicTacToe game in Java and I figured to write more effcient code, I'd make a for loop to create the 9 buttons.

The issue I'm having is figuring out how to test now which button is pressed in order to determine a winner. I have commented out my old test code because it no longer works.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener{

public JFrame window = new JFrame("window");



public String letter = "";
public String lastLetter = "";
public int count = 0;
public boolean win;
public boolean isTieGame;
public static int x;


public TicTacToe()
{

    window.setSize(300,300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    int x;
    JButton[] b = new JButton[9];
    for(x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        b[x] = new JButton();
        window.add(b[x]);
        b[x].addActionListener(this);
    }


    window.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TicTacToe();
    }

public void counter()
    {
        if(count == 1 || count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9)
        {
            letter = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            letter = "O";
        }
    }
/*
public boolean isGameOver()
{

    if(b1.getText().equals(b2.getText()) && b2.getText().equals(b3.getText()) && b1.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b4.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b6.getText()) && b4.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b7.getText().equals(b8.getText()) && b8.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && b7.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b1.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && b1.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b3.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b7.getText()) && b3.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b1.getText().equals(b4.getText()) && b4.getText().equals(b7.getText()) && b1.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b2.getText().equals(b5.getText()) && b5.getText().equals(b8.getText()) && b2.getText() != "")
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if(b3.getText().equals(b6.getText()) && b6.getText().equals(b9.getText()) && b3.getText() != "" )
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else
    {
        win = false;
    }
    return win;
}
*/
public void endOrReset()
    {
        if(win)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lastLetter() + " WINS!");
            int playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?", "Play Again.", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(playAgain == (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION))
            {
            win = false;
            }
            else if(playAgain == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if(isTieGame)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
            int playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?", "Play Again.", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(playAgain == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {


            }
            else if(playAgain == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            }

    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

    count++;
    counter();
    //isGameOver();
    endOrReset();



    ((JButton)a.getSource()).setText(letter);

   }

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   
public String lastLetter()
{
    String lastLetter;
    if(letter == "O")
    {
        lastLetter = "X";
    }
    else
    {
        lastLetter = "O";
    }
    return lastLetter;
}
public boolean isTieGame()
{
    if(count >= 9 && win == false)
    {
        isTieGame = true;
    }
    return isTieGame();
}
}
```

Comment: I think @Phoenix has the best answer, doing it with a windowlistener as you're doing just makes your job a thousand times harder, especially when there are premade tools that can easily handle this job for you

Comment: So, your problem is that you want who won (X || O)? or I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to just make `JButton[] b` a field, so declare it above your constructor.

Also you should use a more descriptive name in that case.

Alternatively you could hold a char Array, in which a button registers the current Players Symbol (X or O), that's how I solved this problem some time ago

Comment: It doesn't solve the answer, but it's a push in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

What I like doing is having a 9 length array independently from the GUI to hold the state of the game, like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Where the indices if you think about it are

```
3*(index/3) + index % 3
```

Where this is usually an enum array, but you can use String array too,

```
public enum State
{
    EMPTY,
    X,
    O;
}
```

And then

```
State[] gridState = new State[9];
for(int i = 0; i < gridState.length; i++) {
    gridState = State.EMPTY;
}
```

And if you initialize your buttons based on GUI according to their indices,

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
    private int index;

    public MyButton(int index) {
        super();
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

And then when someone clicks your button, you can say
    ((MyButton)a.getSource()).getIndex()

And you'll have your index of which button this is.

If the tic tac toe is defined to be 3x3 and 2D, I like checking for wins based on the indexes for which I'd store an array of arrays that hold the horizontal, vertical and diagonal indices that are victorious.

```
int[][] winIndices = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};
```

And then you can check for wins based on

```
public boolean checkWin() {
    for(int[] indexArray : winIndices) {
        boolean same = (gridState[indexArray[0]] == gridState[indexArray[1]]) && 
                       (gridState[indexArray[1]] == gridState[indexArray[2]])
        if(same == true && gridState[indexArray[0]] != State.EMPTY) {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or something like that. I wrote this down once better, but that wasn't on this computer, but it was something similar :)

Comment: WoW, I wish I could think of code that good. I get the overall idea of what this code is doing but I have to study a little longer to really understand it, then I'll implement it into my game. Thanks!